# Testing rails devise sign-out in API with curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, devise, warden

I'm trying to test my API controller with requests via curl.

Login Request (successful)

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"user@example.com\",\"password\":\"password\"}}"
```

I'm following [this](http://lucatironi.github.io/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/) tutorial loosely, but am making modifications since Devise no longer supports auth tokens. I'm using the [simple_token_authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) gem for tokens. My Login requests are successful, and are generating tokens. Here's my api/v1/sessions controller:

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    respond_to :json

    def create
        warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
        render :status => 200,
                :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged in",
                      :data => { :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token } }
    end

    def destroy
        warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
        current_user.update_column(:authentication_token, nil)
        render :status => 200,
               :json => { :success => true,
                          :info => "Logged out",
                          :data => {} }
    end


    def failure
        render :status => 401,
                :json => { :success => false,
                :info => "Login Failed",
                :data => {} }
    end
end
```

I'm trying to test the logout, but can't seem to figure out how I can make a request work with curl. The tutorial has this:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions/\?auth_token\=JRYodzXgrLsk157ioYHf
```

This is returning `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`, and I'm thinking it might be because this request passes auth_token to the controller expecting Devise to know how to handle it? Any help here is much appreciated.

**EDIT** I also noticed my server saying `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`.

**EDIT2** solved CSRF issue with `skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token` but still getting the 401.